# Display and Video Outream in the same ad slot with Prebid.js

Tags: prebid.js

I couldn't find any mention of this on the prebid website.

Is it possible to configure an ad slot in prebid to have both display and video ads?

I am assuming that you can configure the ad slot without a default renderer which means the renderer from the bid response will be used. This page from the publisher documentation seems to suggest you can do it:
http://prebid.org/dev-docs/prebid-1.0-API.html#ad-unit-changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be per the doc you [posted](http://prebid.org/dev-docs/prebid-1.0-API.html#ad-unit-changes)

Theres a great example implementation of this here: http://prebid.org/examples/multi_format_example.html

Essentially you need to include the settings in the `mediaTypes` object in the adUnits for each media type:

```
var adUnits = [{
    code: 'div-banner-native',
    mediaTypes: {
        banner: {
            sizes: [
                [300, 250]
            ]
        },
        native: {
            type: 'image'
        },
    },
    bids: [{
        bidder: 'appnexus',
        params: {
            placementId: 111111111,
        }
    }]
}]
```

Display and Video Outstream should be using the same DFP orders/line items so nothign should need to be changed there (unless you want separate onces per format, and you'd add in targeting to the `hb_format` key value in that case)